# Can the coef be negative in cointegrated stocks?

Tags: programming, cointegration

I'm searching for cointegrated stocks using the Python [CointAnalysis](https://github.com/simaki/cointanalysis) library.
While computing stock prices on a 5 mins time frame, I found that the stocks MNST (Monster Beverage Corp.) and KDP (Keurig Dr. Pepper Inc.) are cointegrated. The computed spread formula is:

```
MNST - (-1.74 * KDP + 112.84)
```

So, my strategy is based on [this article](https://blog.quantinsti.com/pairs-trading-basics/):

`BUY {coeff} KDP` and `SELL 1 MNST` if the spread is one Standard Deviation over 0

`SELL {coeff} KDP` and `BUY 1 MNST` if the spread is one Standard Deviation below 0

But as the coefficient `-1.74` is negative, `KDP` shares quantity is always twisted:

`BUY -1.74 KDP` which is equivalent to `SELL 1.74 KDP`

`SELL -1.74 KDP` which is equivalent to `BUY 1.74 KDP`

So, my strategy becomes:

`SELL 1.74 KDP` and `SELL 1 MNST` if the spread is one Standard Deviation over 0

`BUY 1.74 KDP` and `BUY 1 MNST` if the spread is one Standard Deviation below 0

Is it possible to have a negative coefficient in a cointegration formula?

Does it make sense to go in the same direction on both stocks in cointegration?

Answer (score 0):

Google Bard helps find an explanation for the concept of *inverse relationship*.
When the coefficient is negative, I just have to inverse the direction of the entries on both stocks, not just one. Then if the coeff is `-1.74`, the entry signal becomes:

`SELL 1.74 KDP` and `BUY 1 MNST` if the spread is one Standard Deviation over 0

`BUY 1.74 KDP` and `SELL 1 MNST` if the spread is one Standard Deviation below 0